# React Redux TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, state

I can read my data when I do `const data = useSelector(state => state.user.userData); console.log(data);`

I see that output on my console

```
{_id: "602afea4c03c9a38c8csd5", isAdmin: false, isAuth: true, email: "test@gmail.com", name: "John", …}
```

When I try to take email output in my userData object as below.

```
const data = useSelector(state => state.user.userData.email);
console.log(data);
```

I am having a TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined.

I also tried also name property but It did not work either.

```
const data = useSelector(state => state.user.userData.name);
console.log(data);
```

Nothing changed still same error TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I can not reach any prop inside of userData object

Comment: console logging is asynchronous; is your state?

Comment: I am using Redux so how can I check it out?

Comment: By looking at your code? A `console.log` will update its output once (for example) a promise is resolved. If you’re fetching the state data from an async action you still need to handle rendering before the call has completed.

Answer (score 0):

A "?" helped me to fix my problem. As It is shown below.

const data = useSelector((state) => state.user.userData);
console.log(data?.email);